# Como faço para gerar números aleatórios entre 5 e 30 em Java?

Tags: java, random

Preciso usar o método random e armazená-lo em uma variável de distância, depois mostrar a distancia da cidade A para a cidade B, e da cidade A para a cidade D, ou seja, um número aleatório diferente para cada distância de A.
Após ter criado as instâncias da classe Cidade e suas respectivas distâncias, preciso comparar se da cidade B para a cidade A e da cidade D para a cidade A possuem a mesma quantidade, se o número aleatório é o mesmo.

Na hora de ver as informações das cidades os valores das distâncias não batem, estou usando o método toString pra ver essas informações

```
//Estou usando esse método
while(true){  
    Random r = new Random();  
    int i = r.nextInt(30)+1;


// São acrescentadas as informações das cidades após elas serem criadas
    Cidade cA = new Cidade("A", 200, "Geraldo", "Cidades B e D", r.nextInt(30)+1, r.nextInt(30)+1);
    Cidade cB = new Cidade("B", 250, "Silvia", "Cidades A , C e F", cA.getDistancia1(), r.nextInt(30)+1, r.nextInt(30)+1);
    Cidade cC = new Cidade("C", 220, "João", "Cidades B e D", cB.getDistancia2(), r.nextInt(30)+1);
    Cidade cD = new Cidade("D", 250, "Pedro", "Cidades A , C e E", cA.getDistancia2(), cC.getDistancia2(),r.nextInt(30)+1);
    Cidade cE = new Cidade("E", 350, "Maria", "Cidades D e G", cD.getDistancia3(), r.nextInt(30)+1);
    Cidade cF = new Cidade("F", 300, "Vítor", "Cidades B e G", cB.getDistancia3(), r.nextInt(30)+1);
    Cidade cG = new Cidade("G", 400, "Miguel", "Cidades E e F", cE.getDistancia2(), cF.getDistancia2());



// continuação do código
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
  public static int geraAleatorio(int max, int min) {
        Random random = new Random();
        return (random.nextInt(max - (min - 1)) + min);
    }
```

Isso vai gerar um número aleatório no máximo 30, e no mínimo 5.

 Se quiser você pode converter os valores possíveis do intervalo 30-5(25) números. para uma List, ou outra subclasse(ArrayList> de List.

```
List<Integer> lista = IntStream.generate(()->geraAleatorio(30, 5)).limit(100).distinct().boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

E então exibir: `lista.forEach(e-> System.out.print(e + " "));`

Ou pegar um valor aleatório da lista.

```
int num = lista.stream().findAny().map(Integer::intValue).get();
```